# using session to store data in azure mvc app

Tags: asp.net-mvc, azure, session-state

I have an app hosted in azure and I want to use session storage to hold some navigation data (very small amount).  What are the best practices for this ? Ive read that standard inproc sessions cant be used with Azure, is this correct ?  If so , what are my options ?  Is Redis Cache the best way forward ?

Answer (score 0):

You can't use session in this case, session is guest specific.
If your data is small and do not have too much requests, C# Cache should be the simplest way for you.

Comment: care to elaborate ?

Comment: has anyone got any useful advice at all ?  Im assuming Redis cache is the 'best practice' route to take, would this be correct ?